# Determining where an object in $scope has changed using AngularJS & jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, dom-manipulation

I am developing a scoreboard that displays live scores to an app user asynchronously.

A JSON file is written to and then AngularJS pulls that data and refreshes the `$scope.scores` value.

This is all working peechy keen, except for determining **where** the data has changed, so I can execute a function over only the `div` where the value has changed. I am using an object equality `$watch` to detect changes, but this doesn't tell me where as far as I have gathered...

```
$scope.$watch('data',function(newVal,oldVal){
    log('data has changed');
},true);
```

My goal is to turn the score a different color when it changes. How can I do this?

Figure my DOM structure is similar to:

```
<div class='game'>
    <div class='home'>88</div>
    <div class='away'>75</div>
</div>
<div class='game...
```

My $scope.scores object is like:

```
{
  "Saturday, March 7th, 2015": {
    "610": {
      "away": {
        "scores": 9
      },
      "home": {
        "scores": 2
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any solution is welcome!

Comment: Could you show us which part of the `scores` arrays needs to be watched? (provide us a snippet of one score object).

Comment: Added a trimmed up example the object

Comment: Would you not just store the old json data in a variable and compare it against the ajax/received data.. The method i normally use is a update timestamp.. Basically you include a timestamp of when it was modified.. If that timestamp is less than say 10 seconds old.. You know its new data. By including the timestamp from the server of last changed, you can then then simply check if json.timestamp == ajax.timestamp..

Comment: I was hoping for a slightly less exhaustive situation for when I'm showing many games at once, but I could do that. I am sort of looking for a way to watch a DIV and execute a function on it when it's innerHTML changes. At least that was my last idea. (I will probably end up doing what you suggested though, thanks.)

Comment: Can I assume you want the color change to remain until the user refreshes the page?

Comment: Yea sure. If you can get it to change for me, I can take it from there

Comment: @pXdty Well, if you want to use only the existing data, you could save the initial score for each game and add something along the lines of ng-class='{true:"score-changed"  false: ""}[{{data.gameId.score != gameId.originalScore}}]'. That way each element will get the class only when its score has changed from the first page load.

Comment: i like that. especially when combined with the last_updated being passed into the DOM. Theoretically, I can crawl through the elements having the `score-changed` class and remove said class if the element's last_updated attribute is at least X ms. That would mean looping through a smaller set than the entire data object.

Comment: So, as of yet, there is not a direct way to know which indexes have actually changed without using the work-arounds above? Just trying to close out my answer, but I don't think I can yet. Planning on implementing the above work-arounds today though. Thanks again guys.